# How to configure .htaccess to get access sub directories in a project angularjs

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I ask you to help setting up the .htaccess to get access subdirectories normally.

My .htaccess is configured as follows:

```
# htaccess pushstate html5
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

I can access the directories `www.domain.com/nature` smoothly. However, when access : `www.domain.com/nature/ocean` page is broken (Appears text, video, images only that is not structured. It seems that is not loading the css.) I would set up the .htaccess to get access these subdirectories.

Comment: what do you mean by `page is broken`? what error do you get?

Comment: Appears text, video, images only that is not structured. it seems that is not loading the css

Comment: Was no problem of .htaccess but simply the css link.                                   It read as follows: <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">                      I put like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css"> and it worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was no problem of .htaccess but simply the css link.

It read as follows: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">`

I put like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">` and it worked.